# Añadir campo en class Meta y usarlo en una función

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Actualmente tengo una función dentro del método `save()` que convierte los campos de tipo char en mayúsculas

```
class ModeloBase(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Obtiene todos los campos de tipo charfield
        char_fields = [field.name for field in self._meta.fields if
                       isinstance(field, models.CharField) and not getattr(field, 'choices')]
        for field in char_fields:
            valor = getattr(self, field, False)
            if valor is not None:
                # Elimina los espacios en blanco que no son necesarios
                valor = str(valor)
                valor = " ".join(valor.split())
                # Cambia los caracteres a mayusculas
                setattr(self, field, valor.upper())
```

Quiero crear una variable en la clase meta `uppercase_fields = [ ]` para poder indicar campos específicos para convertir en mayúsculas.

Así como se usan `ordering`, `proxy` u otras que ya están implementadas por defecto.

Comment: Seria ideal que adjuntaras todo el código del el modelo.

Comment: La idea es que sea un modelo abstracto que pueda ser heredado, y usar el campo `uppercase_fields` para definir los campos que serán convertidos en mayúscula

Comment: Si lo tengo claro, ya veré como lograr lo que propones, muy interesante por cierto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera (de esta manera no ensucias tanto el modelo, ademas recomiendo que el atributo `uppercase_fields`, este en mayúsculas para indicar que es una constante, ademas de que en mi opinión se ve mas elegante y pitonico)

```
class Base(models.Model):

    UPPERCASE_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field_name in self.UPPERCASE_FIELDS:
            # En dado caso no exista el attr, ocurrira un error (ya que no pase un tercer argumento), un plus de validacion
            field = getattr(self, field_name)

            # Validamos que sea una cadena el campo, si no es así, 
            # levantamos una excepcion, de esta manera validamos la constante UPPERCASE_FIELDS
            # es decir verificamos que los campos sean "CharField", por asi decirlo

            if not isinstance(field, str): 
                raise AttributeError(f'{field_name} no es un campo CharField!')
            else:
                setattr(self, field_name, field.replace(' ', '').upper())

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Por otra parte no veo necesario crear tantos métodos simplemente para manejar un atributo, es complicarse demasiado en mi opinión, si simplemente quieres restablecer el valor del atributo `UPPERCASE_FIELDS`, se puede hacer esto:

```
>>> Model.UPPERCASE_FIELDS = ['campo']
>>> 
>>> # O por instancia
>>> Model().UPPERCASE_FIELDS = ['campo']
>>>
```

U obtenerlo:

```
>>> Model.UPPERCASE_FIELDS
[...]
>>>
>>> # O nuevamente por intancia
>>> Model().UPPERCASE_FIELDS
[...]
```

Es mucho mas simple que utilizar varios métodos para hacer casi lo mismo.

---

Por cierto en tu solución mencionas que "Eliminas los espacios en blanco que no son necesarios", de la siguiente manera:

```
valor = " ".join(valor.split())
```

No se si estoy entendiendo mal en cuanto a "eliminar los espacios en blanco", pero en realidad eso no elimina los espacios, seria de la siguiente manera para hacerlo (creo que esto es lo que intentabas hacer):

```
valor = "".join(valor.split())
```

Aunque podrías utilizar `replace()`, que es mas simple y mas rapido (que es lo que hice).

---

> Cabe recalcar que esta no es la mejor forma, lo ideal seria utilizar
>   señales, pero como es un modelo abstracto, no se puede.

Y bueno eso seria todo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, lo de los espacios en blanco innecesarios es por ejemplo cuando un usuario ingrese algo como  `"Jaime  Garcia         Rivera "`

Comment: Entre Garcia y Rivera hay 3 espacios pero al parecer stackoverflow los retira visualmente.

Comment: Ok entiendo, un gusto ayudarte!, por otra parte el modelo `User`, el campo `username` específicamente, no permite espacios, así que si era por eso, pues no es necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma, si alguien encuentra algo mas optimo lo agradezco

```
class ModeloBase(models.Model):

    uppercase_fields = []
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.format_fields_to_uppercase()
        super(ModeloBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_uppercase_fields(self):
        """
        Regresa una lista de campos que seran transformados en mayúculas
        """
        return self.uppercase_fields

    def set_uppercase_fields(self, list_fields):
        """
        Establece una lista de campos que seran transformados en mayúculas
        """
        self.uppercase_fields = list_fields

    def format_fields_to_uppercase(self):
        # Obtiene los campos definidos en cada clase hija con el metodo get_uppercase_fields
        for field in self.get_uppercase_fields():
            valor = getattr(self, field, False)
            if valor is not None:
                # Elimina los espacios en blanco que no son necesarios
                valor = str(valor)
                valor = " ".join(valor.split())
                # Cambia los caracteres a mayusculas
                setattr(self, field, valor.upper())
```

Esta sera la clase hija

```
class Persona(ModeloBase):
    nombres = models.CharField()
    apellidos = models.CharField()
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()

    uppercase_fields = ['nombres', 'apellidos']
```

Comment: Al momento de crear un instancia no da ningún tipo de error?

Comment: No, ya lo probé y funciona bien

Comment: Te entendí mal desde el principio, creía que te referías a cambiar el **atributo como tal** a mayúsculas no el valor del campo u atributo xd

Comment: Yo ya por poco y utilizo  metaclases xd

Comment: Jajaja, ok. De igual forma sigo abierto a opciones que puedan ser mas optimas

Comment: Ok ya publicare una alternativa mas limpia, saludos!